# How to make a button disappear on first onclick, wait, then appear a few seconds later in another position?

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick, transition

I have created a button(#nextbtn) that fades out when it is clicked. How do I get it to wait, say 3 seconds, then fade back in 100px below when it was before? And continue doing this each time it is clicked? Here is what I have so far:
CSS:

```
 #nextbtn {
               transition: margin-top 1s, opacity 1s;
                opacity:1;
            }
```

HTML:

```
<button id="nextbtn" onclick="nextClicked()">NEXT</button>
```

JS:

```
function nextClicked() {
                var next = document.getElementById("nextbtn")
                next.style.opacity = "0"
                next.style.marginTop = "-30px"
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

Instead of using margin im using top [ position: relative]

```js
    var next = document.getElementById("nextbtn");
var top1 = 0;

function nextClicked() {

next.style.opacity = "0";

setTimeout(()=>{
top1 += 100;
next.style.opacity = "1";
next.style.top = top1 + "px";

},3000);// 3 sec
}
```

```css
    #nextbtn {
transition: margin-top 1s, opacity 1s;
position: relative;
top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<button id="nextbtn" onclick="nextClicked()">NEXT</button>
```